# unexpected identifier error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting an unexpected identifier error for the following function.

```
function merge (one, two) {
    one.forEach(function(assign){

     //////////this next line is throwing the error////////////
        if (two.some(function(req) req.related == assign.rid)) {
            if (one.some(function(iter) iter.rid == req.rid)) {
                iter.quantity++;
            } else {
                one.push(req);
            }
        }
    });

    return one; 
}
```

The function is intended to operate on an array of objects.

Comment: I'm 2/3ds sure you have to use braces around the anonymous function body, and that that confuses the parser into trying to evaluate `req`: `function(req) { req.related == assign.rid }`

Comment: To make your questions easier to answer well, you should consider [making a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @millimoose You're right, I was afraid if I omitted any code it would remove necessary information.  I'm new enough to javascript to make that mistake.

Comment: Well, I also had in mind adding some code where `merge()` is called with example inputs. It's not obvious what would be valid input here beyond "arrays." But generally, the process of removing code, while retesting to make sure the error still crops up will, in cases like these, usually lets you find the error on your own in the first place. Kind of like a doctor poking a patient all over to figure out where it hurts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed some `{ }` around `.some(function()...`

```
function merge (one, two) {
    one.forEach(function(assign){

        if (two.some(function(req){ req.related == assign.rid})) {
                               // ^-- This one you missed
            if (one.some(function(iter){ iter.rid == req.rid})) {
                                    // ^-- This one you missed as well
                iter.quantity++;
            } else {
                one.push(req);
            }
        }
    });

    return one; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the some function call. It certainly is a function being passed as parameters, so curly brackets are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`.some()` expects function as the parameter.
If you want to pass anonymous function, then use curly braces:

```
if (two.some(function(req) { return req.related == assign.rid; })) 
{
    if (one.some(function(iter) { return iter.rid == req.rid; })) 
    {
        iter.quantity++;
    } else {
        one.push(req);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `open/close braces {}` inside function

writing a function should be like this:

```
$(function(){
//code
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The some function needs curly braces/(paranthesis) to be opened and closed,  please read this link, [this is a good explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the function.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling your functions properly. You need brackets after defining the function's arguments.

For example this is what two.some should look like:

```
two.some(function(req){ req.related == assign.rid })
```